# Datastore strong consistency by loading saved entity by key

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

If I save an entity to the datastore and then right after load the entity by it's key, will the program wait and ensure strong consistency?

```
thing.setValue(newValue);
ofy().save().entity(thing).now();
Thing updatedThing = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();
```

Does `updatedThing` contain the new value?

Is this a good method to ensure strong consistency for a case when I want to update an entity?

Comment: lookups by key (and ancestor queries) are strongly consistent. [Link: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#strong-consistency-on-reading-entity-values-and-indexes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, key lookups are always consistent in the datastore. From the table at the beginning of the [Eventual Consistency in Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#eventual-consistency-in-cloud-datastore):

> ```
> [Lookup by key][2] (get())    Strong consistency
> ```

But there's a catch - if you do both the write and the read **inside the same transaction** the read won't see the written info. From [Isolation and consistency](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/transactions#isolation_and_consistency):

> This consistent snapshot view also extends to reads after writes
>   inside transactions. Unlike with most databases, queries and gets
>   inside a Cloud Datastore transaction do *not* see the results of
>   previous writes inside that transaction. Specifically, if an entity is
>   modified or deleted within a transaction, a query or get returns the
>   *original* version of the entity as of the beginning of the transaction, or nothing if the entity did not exist then.